# How to hide the square displaying in the left bottom of my chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I want to hide the little square (lower left). How can I do this ?

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false)`